# How to JOIN tag_map in a normalized database

Tags: mysql, database, join, normalization

Consider an standard normalized many-to-many tag system (three tables of articles, tags, tag_map). I want to get a list of tags with associated articles; for example

```
Tag    Article_IDs
tag1   1,5,7
tag2   3,4,5,7,8
.....
```

How should I `JOIN` the tables to generate this list?

The naive way to simply count the number of rows in tag_map WHERE tag='something'. Badly, for this method, we need a separate query for every tag. For example, to generate a list for 20 tags, we need 20 queries (which is not rational). I hope to do this is one query with `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acomplish this with [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation function. They are a lot of samples in stackoverflow.

```
SELECT tag.id,
 GROUP_CONCAT(post.post_id)
 FROM 
  posts 
  inner join 
  post_tag on ...
  inner join 
  tags on ...
 GROUP BY tag.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (but this is Oracle only, I don't know the equivalent of `wm_concat()` on other databases):

```
select t.tagname, wm_concat(m.articleid) from tags t, tag_map m where t.id = m.tagid group by t.tagname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select t.Tag, Group_Concat(a.Article_ID)
From tag_map tm
Join tag t on tm.tag_id = t.tag_id
Join articles a on tm.article_id = a.article_id
Group By t.Tag
```